# How to ignore cHash when working with urls that contain an id?

Tags: typo3, tt-news

The website that I'm working on uses cooluri to format the urls. In the case of news, the "parameters" column of the "link_cache" table stores the parameters like this:

```
a:3:{s:5:"cHash";s:32:"eea2db734d63b661abaab43d86fd3bb5";s:2:"id";s:5:"15503";s:18:"tx_ttnews[tt_news]";s:6:"142085";}
```

, or in a more readable way:

```
{  
   "cHash":"eea2db734d63b661abaab43d86fd3bb5",
   "id":"15503",
   "tx_ttnews[tt_news]":"142085"
}
```

My problem is, that there are lots of pages where these urls are inserted in content elements like in the example below, and ofcourse the cHash parameters don't match.

> website.com/news/some-title/431731b3f9d391a54c9ee48467ca4bb4.html

Now because of this I get the following error message on the news single view page:

> no news_id given

Is there a clean way to solve this issue? I was told that changing the links in the backend is not an option. Also, the links are very old, and the option "oldlinksvalidfor"  is set to 365.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration goes in the  block. Here is a configuration for Ext:CoolUri. This working fine for me (with tt_news) this will remove cHash from the URL. You have an additional configuration for managing caching and all.

```
<predefinedparts>
    <part>
        <parameter>no_cache</parameter>
    </part>
    <part>
        <parameter>cHash</parameter>
    </part>

<!-- common patterns -->

<!-- parts defined this way will be removed from URL -->
<part>
    <parameter>paramC</parameter>
</part>
<!-- this will prefix a value with "prefix-". Cannot be localized.
-->
<part key="prefix-(.*)" regexp="1">
    <parameter>paramD</parameter>
</part>

<part key="page-(.*)" regexp="1">
    <parameter>array[k5]</parameter>
</part>
<!-- if parameter matches value, key will be added to URL 
with mutliple values, use valuemaps
-->
<part key="thisWillAppearInUrl">
    <parameter>paramE</parameter>
    <value>ifParamEMatcesThisValue</value>
</part>
</predefinedparts>
```

Hope this will helpful to you.

Greetings!